# PHP Undefined index - Isset() is false when index is in array

Tags: php, arrays, isset, array-key-exists

I'm not able to figure out what the issue is here. I have an associative array with predefined indexes and when trying to access one of the indexes, I'm getting the undefined index error, here's the code,

```
        if(!isset($score_value[$index])){
            echo $index . ' isnt in array: <br/>';
            print_r($score_value);
            exit;
        }
        print_r($score_value[$index]);
```

The output was this:

`pi_cholesterol` isn't in array:

```
Array ( 
    [pi_overall_health] => Array ( 
        [4] => 4 [1] => 1 [2] => 4 [3] => 1 
    ) 
    [pi_bmi] => Array ( 
        [Healthy Weight] => 4 [Obese] => 3 [Overweight] => 3 
    ) 
    [pi_cholesterol] => Array ( 
        [Yes - its level is too high] => 6 [Yes - its level is ok] => 3 [No] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

As you can see `pi_cholesterol` is an index in the array but for some reason `isset()` is flagging it as not being in the array, same thing happens if I try with `array_key_exists()`. There might be some simple thing I'm overlooking but I can't see it.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: what is $index == ?

Comment: In  this case $index = 'pi_cholesterol'

Comment: @Ross So the array you included in the question is the output from `print_r($score_value);`?

Comment: Yes the array in the question is the output from `print_r($score_value);`

Comment: loop for that array and var_dump each key of it

Comment: You might have a typo somewhere, a sneaky whitespace can make man go mad. Could you do what @VidishPurohit suggested and hash every key, then compare it to the hash of your `$index`. It could literally be a sneaky space or tab that causes this problem.

Comment: Make sure `$index` does not contain padding spaces.

Comment: check this [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7aa200531de6bfde8e1c47181a8690afc496adda) its working. check with $index = trim($index); before checking condition.

Comment: Key:string(17) "pi_overall_health" 
Value:array(4) { [4]=> int(4) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(4) [3]=> int(1) } 
Key:string(6) "pi_bmi" 
Value:array(3) { ["Healthy Weight"]=> int(4) ["Obese"]=> int(3) ["Overweight"]=> int(3) } 
Key:string(14) "pi_cholesterol" 
Value:array(3) { ["Yes - its level is too high"]=> int(6) ["Yes - its level is ok"]=> int(3) ["No"]=> int(1) }

Comment: Is the result of `foreach ($score_value as $key => $value){
                echo '<br/>Key:';
                var_dump($key);
                echo '<br/>Value:';
                var_dump($value);
            }`

Comment: @Ross it should work because it's working for my case check here https://3v4l.org/nrCnj

Comment: @Ross are you using any loop please update your full code

Comment: @Ross Can you update your full code as?

Comment: what about `$index  = trim($index);` (@mjh stated `a sneaky whitespace` somewhere ?) EDIT: too late, already own-answered by OP... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my own stupid mistake, $index was being overwritten in another place in the code and was being appended with a trailing whitespace.

Mjh, axiac and rahul_m suggesting to use trim() helped me solve this.

Comment: Good! I was wondering the same! That's why I asked for full code! :)